# how to import external javascript library in angular4 if there is no type definition(*.d.ts) file is available for that library

Tags: angular, typescript

Since i am new to angular and typescript files.

The very first question is , Is it possible to import external library if there is no type definition file(*.d.ts) is available in that specific library ?

if yes then please tell me how can i achieve this thing and

if not then is there any work around for this ?

our project is in " angular 4 " and since i want to import library in front-end(browser-side) i am not suppose to use `require('*')`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The goto for your problem is the DefinetlyTyped Project (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). 
They have a search engine to search for the respective types package. Check it out: https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/

Comment: Thanks but i have already checked this, i cant able to find typed file. is there any another way to do?